# Refreshing same URL gives 404 not found in angular

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, angular8

I have hosted my angular application on a server. When I click the server url , it redirects me to login page. However, when I refresh the same url suffixed with login, it gives me 404 not found error.
The original url given is without login  suffix.
Please help.

[image]

[image]

In app.routing.module.ts, I have configured router paths like this:

[image]

Comment: You need to configure your webserver: https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Comment: Did the answer provided work?

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks Lucas.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This happens with Angular sometimes. There's a few different reasons why this happens that I have seen. One because URL changes happen using simple js, and also to block web crawlers since there is no content on a given link.. Anyways, if you want a quick fix, you can use a hash approach. This approach will make your links look like so:
`http://link/#/page` compared to `http://link/page` (note the `#`)

### Option 1

In your `app.module.ts`, add imports for `HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy`:

`import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';`
, then in your NgModule Provider:

`{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}`

This could look something like the following:

**App.Module.Ts**

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### Option 2

Another way is going to be by using `RouterModule.forRoot...` with `useHash: true` arg.

In your **routing module or app module**:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ],
```

### Option 3

If these don't work, or they don't give you the desired outcome (you may not want the has approach), then I would recommend looking into AngularUniversal, or look into serverside approaches to configure your server to serve the index.html file for each route defined. This is a longer more complex approach, but hopefully the above options will suffice.

Comment: Option 1 works for me with angular 12 on IIS

Comment: Option 2:  { useHash: true } worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Option 2 worked for me too (Angular 12), thanks

Comment: Beautiful URL without "#"
I sent the ticket to the host server company, they configured the web server
For more information, ```visit: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml```

Comment: Option 1 `PathLocationStrategy` worked for me instead of `HashLocationStrategy`